# How to implement Facebook connect when app is a shell browser, not native app

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I've just implemented Facebook connect/oauth in my web app and finally got it working.  We also have two mobile apps (iOS and Android), both of which are not native apps, but rather "shell browsers" (they effectively just display the mobile version of our site in a nice package).

Our Facebook connect implementation isn't working on mobile as is, but I'm not sure why - the asynchronous js to initialize the SDK, grab the cookie, etc., is on our mobile pages just like the full versions.  Is there something about the shell browser that prevents this from working (e.g. the cookie from getting stored)?

Is there an easy workaround for this, or do we have to flesh out the app a bit and implement the iOS/Android SDKs and single sign-on?

**Edit: a bit more detail about what's happening ->

We go to the app, click login with Facebook.  Via the js sdk, we're taken to Facebook's little authorize window *in the mobile browser* (not within the app, as all external links are set to open outside the app).  Everything's ok with the authorize window, but when we click through to authorize the app and log in, we're taken to a blank page in the mobile browser.  That is, we don't go back to the app and call the redirect that is set to get triggered upon authorization/login.

I suppose there could be two solutions to this (?): should we make it so that these facebook dialogues/links open *within* the app (so we never leave and go to the mobile browser)? Or is there a way to have the mobile browser redirect us back to the app that originally called it (so that when the fb dialogue opens in the mobile browser, we accept and are taken back to the app)?

Comment: Do you have any error messages or info on your shell browser (I assume you mean something like PhoneGap)?

Comment: We/our mobile guy wrote the apps himself (he's since left) simply using load_url and such to load the mobile site within the app (with some native app features like location tied in), so not quite PhoneGap but probably similar.